# Custom session SaveHandler in zf3 with Doctrine

Tags: php, session, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

How to implement sessions in database when using ZF3 and Doctrine?

Manual says:

> There may be cases where you want to create a save handler where a
>   save handler currently does not exist. Creating a custom save handler
>   is much like creating a custom PHP save handler. All save handlers
>   must implement Zend\Session\SaveHandler\SaveHandlerInterface.
>   Generally if your save handler has options you will create another
>   options class for configuration of the save handler.

I tried to create custom class implementing this interface, but I get the following error:

`expects a class implementing Zend\Session\Storage\StorageInterface'`

with this config:

```
 'session_storage' => [
//        'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class (with array storage works ok)
        'type' => \Application\Session\SaveHandler\Doctrine::class (tried to implement suggested interface)
    ],
```

Note that manual suggests `SaveHandlerInterface`, but expects `StorageInterface`.

Any example how to to this?

**Edit:**

My current implementation.

In `global.php`:

```
  'session_config' => [
        // Session cookie will expire in 1 hour.
        'cookie_lifetime' => 60*60*1,
        // Session data will be stored on server maximum for 30 days.
        'gc_maxlifetime'     => 60*60*24*30,
    ],
    // Session manager configuration.
    'session_manager' => [
        // Session validators (used for security).
        'validators' => [
            RemoteAddr::class,
            HttpUserAgent::class,
        ]
    ],
    // Session storage configuration.
    'session_storage' => [
        'type' => \Application\Session\Storage\Doctrine::class,
    ],
    'session_containers' => [
        'UserSession'
    ]
```

in `Module.php`:

```
/**
     * This method is called once the MVC bootstrapping is complete.
     */
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();



        // The following line instantiates the SessionManager and automatically
        // makes the SessionManager the 'default' one
        /** @var SessionManager $sessionManager */
        $sessionManager = $serviceManager->get(SessionManager::class);

        $entityManager =  $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        /** @var Doctrine $storage */
        $storage = $sessionManager->getStorage();
        $storage->setEntityManager($        
    }
```

in `Application\Session\Storage\Doctrine.php`:

```
class Doctrine implements
    IteratorAggregate,
    StorageInterface,
    StorageInitializationInterface
{
    public function setEntityManager($em) {  
        $this->entityManager = $em;
    }

    // ...
    // other functions as required by interfaces
}
```

This works, but the drawback is that the Doctrine Storage will be available only in this module, and I specifically inject it on each request (Boostrap), not when it's really needed (Factory).

**Update: **

I wrote `SaveHandler`, but looks like valued are not preserved after requests.

Here's the code:

```
    class Doctrine extends ArrayStorage implements SaveHandlerInterface {

    /**
     * @param string $session_id
     * @return string Encdoded session data string
     */
    public function read($session_id)
    {
        $entity = $this->getEntity($session_id);
        if ($entity) {
            return $entity->getSessionData();
//          sample output:
//          string '__ZF|a:2:{s:20:"_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME";d:1501933765.497678;s:6:"_VALID";a:3:{s:25:"Zend\Session\Validator\Id";s:26:"3kr15rhi6ijhneu7rruro9gr76";s:33:"Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:36:"Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent";s:133:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/57.0.2987.98 Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36";}}FlashMessenger|C:23:"Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject":205:{a:4:{s:7:"storage";a:0:{}s:4:"flag";i:2;s:13:"iteratorClass";s:13:"ArrayI'... (length=645)
//          note that counter is not present            
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $session_id
     * @param string $session_data Encoded session data string
     * @return bool
     */
    public function write($session_id, $session_data)
    {
//        sample input ($session_data):
//        string '__ZF|a:2:{s:20:"_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME";d:1501934933.9573331;s:6:"_VALID";a:3:{s:25:"Zend\Session\Validator\Id";s:26:"3kr15rhi6ijhneu7rruro9gr76";s:33:"Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr";s:9:"127.0.0.1";s:36:"Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent";s:133:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/57.0.2987.98 Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36";}}UserSession|C:23:"Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject":223:{a:4:{s:7:"storage";a:1:{s:7:"counter";i:1;}s:4:"flag";i:2;s:13:"iteratorCla'... (length=918)
//        (note that counter variable is set)

        $entity = $this->getEntity($session_id);

        $entity->setSessionData($session_data);
        $entity->setLifetime($this->getLifeTime());

        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush($entity);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $session_id
     * @return Entity|null
     */
    public function getEntity($session_id)
    {
        $this->entity = $this->getRepository()->find($session_id);

        if (!$this->entity) {
            $this->entity = new $this->entityName;
            $this->entity->setId($session_id);
        }

        return $this->entity;
    }

    //  ....

 }
```

Comment: When exactly do you get this error?

Comment: I think when the session service is registered in session manager.

Comment: I have written a very simply POC snippet with trivial SaveHandlerInterface implementation. No errors so far.

Comment: @akond, how do you inject dependencies (eg. EntityManager) into SaveHandler? Would you share your code?

Comment: I didn't inject any dependency. Just old good `new`s. It would be better if you showed your code.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you need those interfaces implemented, because `SaveHandlerInterface` is needed for PHP, and `StorageInterface` for ZF3. You storage handler is kind of a gateway between them.

This should work. You can inject all the dependencies inside the factory.

**Application/src/DoctrineSaveHandler.php**

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Session\SaveHandler\SaveHandlerInterface;
use Zend\Session\Storage\ArrayStorage;

class DoctrineSaveHandler extends ArrayStorage implements SaveHandlerInterface
{
    public function close () {}
    public function destroy ($session_id) {}
    public function gc ($maxlifetime) {}
    public function open ($save_path, $name)  {}
    public function read ($session_id)  {}
    public function write ($session_id, $session_data)  {}
}
```

**config/autoload/global.php**

```
"service_manager" => [
    'aliases' => [
        \Zend\Session\SaveHandler\SaveHandlerInterface::class => \Zend\Session\Storage\StorageInterface::class
    ],
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\Session\Storage\StorageInterface::class => function () {
            // -------------------------------
            // YOU NEED A PROPER FACTORY HERE!
            // -------------------------------
            return new DoctrineSaveHandler();
        },
    ]
]
```

Comment: This allowed me to inject `EntityManager`, but once I implemented `read()` and `write()` methods, encoded values are saved to database, but not handled properly (session container has no values at all). Probably there are some problems with seralizing/unserializing the data. I've updated the question with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I did not use doctrine with save handler feature for managing session. But let me tell you about how each part of `Zend\Session` should be constructed, specially for `SessionManager::class`.

`SessionArrayStorage::class` implements `Zend\Session\Storage\StorageInterface` and is used for storing session data in favor of `SessionManager::class`.

Actually this part of `Zend\Session` does a great thing. It works in replace of `$_SESSION` superglobal and uses `ArrayObject::class` from `Zend\Stdlib`. It would give you a great flexibility meaning you would be able to use these features: property access, metadata storage, locking, and immutability. (Honestly I did not use all of them).

```
'session_storage' => [
    // 'type' => SessionArrayStorage::class (with array storage works ok)
    'type' => \Application\Session\SaveHandler\Doctrine::class (tried to implement suggested interface)
],
```

Now the point is that you are using a custom save handler instead of a storage which is not right thing. Because a save handler does not implement `Zend\Session\Storage\StorageInterface`. This is why you are getting that type of error.

A save handler is generally used to store session data in database, files or caching systems. As you are making a custom save handler meaning you are implementing `Zend\Session\SaveHandler\SaveHandlerInterface`. Therefore, you have to work with `open($savePath, $name)`, `read($id)`, `write($id, $data)`, `destroy($id)` and so on.

So to fully configure `SessionManager::class` for managing session you need to provide three things in it: session configuration, session storage and save handler. For example

```
$sessionManager = new SessionManager(
    $sessionConfig,
    $sessionStorage,
    // provide your save handler here
    $sessionSaveHandler
);

// this keeps this configuration in mind in later calls of 'Container::class'
Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
return $sessionManager;
```

Now we have configured `SessionManager::class`. We would be able to call this when we need it. For example, after one has verified with one's login credentials.

```
$session = $e->getApplication()
    ->getServiceManager()
    ->get(SessionManager::class);
$session->start();
```

After this we would be able to use `Container::class` part of `Zend\Session` component as the follows

```
// this would use the above configuration 
$container = new Container('initialized');

$session->getSaveHandler()->open('path', 'session-name');

// Write data to db, files etc
// "$contents" must be serialized data; coentents can be: id, email etc
$session->getSaveHandler()->write($session->getId(), $contents);

// Read data
$storedData = $session->getSaveHandler()->read($session->getId());
```

Now we would be able to use any custom property and store values like

```
$container->storedData = $storedData;
$container->remoteAddr = 127.0.0.1;
```

Next where we need to retrieve these values we can get them thus

```
$container = new Container('initialized');
print_r($container->storedData);

//or
echo $container->remoteAddr;
```

Hope this would help you a bit!

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to inject EntityManager dependency into custom session storage class (which name you may set changing `type` in global.php config) to have it accessible in all application modules. For now I do this in Module.php, retrieving storage instance and passing Entity manager. But this way I inject complete object, not a factory, and this object is accessible only in current module. How to inject EntityManager factory in session manager?

Comment: Well, first you need to create factories for your `Doctrine::class` and `EntityManager::class`. Then inject `EntityManager::class` into setter method of `Doctrine::class` while creating factory. Then use service manager for calling them where you need. Thanks